# How to get the process start time in HH:MM:SS format using unix shell script?

Tags: bash

I am using  the following :

```
ptime=`ps aux | grep $PROCESS | awk {'print $9'} | head -$i | tail -1
```

but I am getting the start time of the process in `HH::MM` format .

but I want the time in `HH:MM:SS` format using shell script

Comment: first of all your syntax is wrong: `awk {'print $9'}` change it with ` awk '{print $9}'`. which OS are you using ? normally ps aux show also the `SS` when you print time. are you sure that the column `$9` is the correct one?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ps` with options as below from man page

Info from the man page of `ps` on a Linux machine.

```
-A          Select all processes. Identical to -e.
-o format   user-defined format.
            format is a single argument in the form of a blank-separated
            or comma-separated list, which offers a way to specify
            individual output columns.
etime       ELAPSED  elapsed time since the process was started,    in the
            form [[dd-]hh:]mm:ss.


  ps -Ao pid,etime,comm | grep <process>

$ ps -Ao pid,etime,comm | grep sftp-server

85587  16-02:17:01 sftp-server
```

Comment: Add a `| awk {'print $2'}` along with the output if you need the time alone.

Comment: Or combine grep and awk into one awk: `... | awk '/'"$pid"'/'{print $2}`

Comment: @Swapnil Sharma: Can you confirm and accept the answer if it is working? So that it can be made useful for others?